# Close port on killing python the process with children

Tags: python, port, popen, kill

When my python program is killed with -9 normally it also closes the port it's listening.

BUT when it has some child processes running created with Popen (which I don't really need to kill on killing parent), while killing -9 the parent it seems to leave the port in use.

How can I force to close the port even if there are children?

Comment: your program can't close port on SIGKILL signal (`-9`), it is probably done by the kernel then the process is already dead.

Answer (score 0):

ok I've got it seems like close_fds=True while doing Popen solves the issue.

Comment: another way is to create the connections using non-inheritable file descriptors. It is default on [Python 3.4+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/) though `close_fds=True` is default since Python 3.2 on Unix. It works because `close_fds=True` avoids leaking file descriptors to child processes.

Comment: yes, it should work if you pass `close_fds=True` explicitly. On Python 3.2+ on Unix, you don't need to.